# Entanglement in a uniform magnetic field

Tags: quantum-mechanics, magnetic-fields, quantum-entanglement

Suppose we throw only one particle (1) with spin-1/2 into a uniform magnetic field while letting free the other entangled particle (2). The state of the particle-2 will not be affected and this is a known fact.

But, if the uniform magnetic field is strong enough, it will not only flip the spin of the first particle, also it will interact with its magnetic dipole causing the spin to align in the direction of the field. And because there is a change in the magnetic field of the spin, there will be an emission of a photon. For example, if the initial state of the spin was in the same direction of the uniform field, no photon will be emitted but if it was in the opposite direction then, a photon should be emitted. Therefore, this also can be considered as a measurement since we obtained information about the particle by observing whether a photon will be emitted or not.

This seems to contradict with the fact that the magnetic field will only operate on the spin by a unitary operator 
$$\exp \left(\frac{-iHt}{h}\right) = \exp \left(\frac{i\gamma B_0 S_z t}{h}\right). $$ 
This unitary operator is not Hermitian and therefore can not be considered as measurement.

Comment: This is rather interesting as, to get an entangled spin 1/2 state, you have two possibilities. Either $S=1,\ S_z=0$ or $S=0,S_z=0$. In both cases you have no unitary evolution.

Comment: But will I get a photon or not? Also why no unitary evolution as long as the magnetic field works only on one particle?

Comment: You have neither spin flip nor alignment along the field so, no photon whatsoever. In order to get a meaningful effect either the field is varying in time or is inhomogeneous.

Comment: Firstly, why the spin does not flip into the direction of the field and precessing with Larmor frequency? I suppose, it is a well known treatment of a spin in the uniform magnetic field which ends up with Larmor frequency. Secondly, the change of the magnetic dipole moment with the time (from initial state before entering the field to the final state once enters it) is the one which create photon not the change in the main magnetic field. Please correct me if wrong.

Comment: You are seeing this process from a classical standpoint. Your Hamiltonian is $\mu B_0 S_z$. This all you need. In such a case, the application of time evolution amounts to multiply by identity for spin entangled states.

Comment: From quantum viewpoint as well because S is the Pauli spinator. I did not understand your last sentence. The point of my question is, what happens for the particle in a uniform magnetic field? this is very simple question. Will it preccess around $B_0$ only or will it emit photon as well once enters the field? Also precessing alone means there is rotating magnetic field of the electron (which should also emits EM radiation) , will that happen as well? Once solving the problem of single particle, we can formulate what will happen to its entangled one.

Comment: There is no precession from a quantum standpoint. You keep on describing the process classically and this is wrong. You have unitary evolution and states. In this case, the entangled spin states are eigenstates of your Hamiltonian with 0 eigenvalue. So, you get no evolution whatsoever. It depends on the value of $S_z$. If your state is $|S=1,S_z=1\rangle$ you will get a phase factor on your state given by $e^{-i\mu B_0 t}$ and that's all. But this is not an entangled state.

Comment: Sorry your answer is not clear for me and contradict your first comment.

Comment: I do not think so but my view is that you need some in-depth clarifications about foundations of quantum mechanics.

Comment: I assume you may not notice that only one particle is within the field, do you say that in this condition, the time evolution is still represented by identity operator? How the magnetic field in one location affect the other particle?

Comment: Let me state the problem formally. You have your Hamiltonian $H=\mu B_0S_z$ and you have to solve the Schrödinger equation $H|\psi\rangle=i\hbar\partial |\psi\rangle/\partial t$. So, what is your initial state $|\psi(0)\rangle$ to find the solution?

Comment: The initial state; $|\psi(0)\rangle=\alpha|UP_1 \rangle |DOWN_2\rangle +\beta|DOWN_1 \rangle |UP_2\rangle$. Then I only take the first particle-1 and let it enter a uniform magnetic field $B_0$. The second particle is away from $B_0$. And my question; what will happen to the first particle, will it emit photon? will it precess with Larmor frequency? and will the entanglement break?

Comment: That is the point. When you normalize that state you realize that you have got an eigenstate of $S_z$ with value $s_z=0$ and you are done. The other way is the singlet state. In such a case you will have a minus sign between the two factors.

Comment: Sorry the correct state is; $$|\psi(0)\rangle=\alpha|UP_1 \rangle |DOWN_2\rangle -\beta|DOWN_1 \rangle |UP_2\rangle$$ All my questions still hold on this state.

Comment: I made this detailed calculation; $|\psi(t)\rangle=e^\frac{-iHt}{\hbar}|\psi(0)\rangle$ But because the time evolution operator in my case will only work on the first particle, then $|\psi(t)\rangle=(e^\frac{-iHt}{\hbar} \otimes 1)|\psi(0)\rangle$ gives $|\psi(t)\rangle=(e^\frac{-iHt}{\hbar} \otimes 1)[\alpha|+_1 \rangle |-_2\rangle -\beta|-_1 \rangle |+_2\rangle]$ -> $|\psi(t)\rangle=\alpha e^\frac{-iHt}{\hbar}|+_1 \rangle |-_2\rangle -\beta e^\frac{-iHt}{\hbar}|-_1 \rangle |+_2\rangle$ $=\alpha e^{iuB_0t}|+_1 \rangle |-_2\rangle -\beta e^{-uB_0t}|-_1 \rangle |+_2\rangle$ ?still entangled???

Answer (score 1):

In general, the interaction between the particle and the magnetic field, can cause entanglement between the two. This can lead to entanglement between the system (the two particles) and the environment (whether or not a photon is emitted). Such an interaction would give rise to decoherence, in other words, to a loss of entanglement in the original system.

If on the other hand here is now interaction with the environment, then the action on the one particle is just a local unitary operation. Such local unitary operations do not affect the entanglement of the state. In other words, one can change the state of the one particle without touching the other particle and then the entanglement will remain in tact.

BTW, the unitary operator on its own is not a measurement. You would need to include to observation of the photon into your analysis to represent the measurement. Then what you'll end up with would not be only the unitary operator anymore.

Comment: I am not even sure whether a photon will be emitted or no, that is why I am asking. My question is; do I expect a photon, hence a measurement of the spin state, or just a flip of the spin in the direction of the field with a Larmor frequency? If the first case holds, then the state of the twin particle will be known as well. If not, then it will be just a break of entanglement due to interaction with the field.

Comment: Added a bit about the case when there is no interaction with the environment.

Comment: Thank you. Suppose the local magnetic field on one particle is in the $z-direction$. Now, because only one particle out of two is under a local unitary operator, it should have the expected value of $Z$-component along the direction of the field, while the other $X$ and $Y$ components precess with Larmor frequency. Is this a form of measurement?  Because without the magnetic field, the expected value is 0, while within the field, it is proportional to $\frac{\hbar}{2}$.